# Insert unicode text into Oracle database table

Tags: database, oracle, unicode, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I create a table in ***OracleDB 11c*** through ***SQL Developer 4.1.1***

```
CREATE TABLE FAC.FAC_CODE_CPQLDN(    
    ID NUMBER(10), 
    CODE NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, 
    NAME NLOB, 
    NOTE NLOB, 
    PARENT_ID NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT FAC_CODE_CPQLDN_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

After that, I insert data into this table

```
REM INSERTING into FAC_CODE_CPQLDN
SET DEFINE OFF;
insert into FAC_CODE_CPQLDN(ID, CODE, NAME, NOTE, PARENT_ID) values (1, 'C1.1', 'Chi phí công ty', '', 0);
```

But I get the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
```

Please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the characterset of your database? `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` I would avoid using NVARCHAR2s and NLOBs if possible and just have a UTF-8 (AL32UTF8 in Oracle's terminology) database.

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET------AL32UTF8

Comment: So, you've already got a unicode database. Try to re-create the table with only VARCHAR2 columns and re-insert.

Comment: I tried to re-create the table with only VARCHAR2 but still meet this error. When inserting with Vietnamese language, SQL Error: ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert varchar2 values to RAW-format before insert into BLOB fields -

```
insert into FAC_CODE_CPQLDN(ID, CODE, NAME, NOTE, PARENT_ID) 
values (1, 'C1.1', UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('Chi phí công ty'), null, 0);
```

Comment: In this case, should I use NLOB or BLOB? VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2?

Comment: Small unicode string you can store in NVARCHAR2 fields, large - into NCLOB. BLOB usually used for binary-data, not for strings.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is unnecessary, you have a database with the characterset AL32UTF8, i.e. one that's already in a unicode characterset - UTF-8.

If you declare the columns as a VARCHAR2 then you should be able to just insert the data.

```
SQL> create table fac_code_cpqldn(name varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into fac_code_cpqldn values ('chi phí công ty');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

NVARCHAR2s, NLOBs etc. are far more difficult to work with than the standard datatypes. For the avoidance of doubt; this is a 11.2 database:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
---------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

You can find out your characterset from [NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_5147.htm#REFRN29030), as I originally commented:

```
SQL> select value
  2    from nls_database_parameters
  3   where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

VALUE
-------------------------------------------
AL32UTF8
```